# Manjaro ncurses5-compat-libs installation

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman, pac-manager

I'm trying to install the `ncurses5-compat-libs` package, but cannot because of the following problems.

***What I tried:***

**1. yay ncurses5-compat-libs**

There are 2 types of errors:

- Checking `Y` and to add the key, results in the error message below

  gpg: keyserver receive failed: Permission denied
  ==> Error: Problem importing keys
- Checking `N` to not add the key produces

  ==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
  ncurses-6.1.tar.gz ... FAILED (unknown public key 702353E0F7E48EDB)
  ==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
  Error downloading sources: ncurses5-compat-libs

**2. sudo gpg --recv-keys C52048C0C0748FEE227D47A2702353E0F7E48EDB**

I've tried to add the key manually, but it didn't work.

**3. sudo gpg --recv-keys 702353E0F7E48EDB**

Also I've tried to add it manually, but it didn't work

**4. yay -S --noconfirm --needed ncurses5-compat-libs**

**5. Trying to follow this [forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204240)**

**6. I've tried to clone the repository by hand by following**

```
git clone http://aur.archlinux.org/ncurses5-compat-libs.git 
cd ncurses5-compat-libs
sudo gpg --recv-keys C52048C0C0748FEE227D47A2702353E0F7E48EDB
makepkg -sic
cd ..
sudo rm -r ncurses5-compat-libs
```

This leaves me back from where I started...

```
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    ncurses-6.1.tar.gz ... FAILED (unknown public key 702353E0F7E48EDB)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
Error downloading sources: ncurses5-compat-libs
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `gpg --recv-keys C52048C0C0748FEE227D47A2702353E0F7E48EDB`?

Comment: `gpg: key 702353E0F7E48EDB: 174 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 702353E0F7E48EDB: public key "Thomas Dickey <dickey@invisible-island.net>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1`

Comment: This looks like the import was successful. If it still doesn’t work leave a comment on [the AUR page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and tried everything you did with the same results.  I almost lost hope until I found [bickman2k's comment](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/#comment-743862) at https://aur.archlinux.org:

> If you are having trouble importing the key, try the following command:
> gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 702353E0F7E48EDB

That worked for me